# tornado redis error: "finish() called twice"

Tags: python, redis, tornado, long-polling

```
class RedisHandler(BaseHandler):
@tornado.web.authenticated
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.engine
def post(self):
    self.client = tornadoredis.Client()
    self.client.connect()
    yield tornado.gen.Task(self.client.subscribe,'notification')
    self.client.listen(self.on_message)

def on_message(self,msg):
    if msg.kind == 'message':
        self.finish(dict(complete=True,message=msg.body))
    return
```

The above code raises:

> RuntimeError: finish() called twice

It may be caused by using async operations without the @asynchronous decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you don't unsubscribe/disconnect from Redis when you call `self.finish()`, and so when another message arrives, `on_message()` is called again:

```
def on_message(self,msg):
    if msg.kind == 'message':

        self.finish(dict(complete=True,message=msg.body))

        self.client.unsubscribe('notification')
        self.client.disconnect()
```